# Git Push Not Updating Source

Tags: git, egit

The only version-control software I've really used extensively is Subversion. I like git's feature set and performance though, so I'm choosing to use it for version control with my future projects.

I'm using the eGit plugin for Eclipse. My problem is that when I push upstream (which is reported successful), the source code at the origin isn't updated. If I look at the version history, I can see the pushed commit.

If this was Subversion, I would do an 'update', and my changes would be synced at the origin. This is a little different obviously though as I'm no longer dealing with a single, centralized repository.

Is there something I'm doing wrong or not doing at all that I can do to update the source at the origin? If the answers could be geared towards using the eGit interface rather than the git command line utility, it would be especially helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "the source code at the origin" do you mean the working tree at the origin?  You need to `git checkout` the branch on the origin machine in order to update the working tree to the latest.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I guess in eGit there is no 'commit' though-- you have to do a 'hard reset'.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you've added and committed anything to your local repo?

On the command line this would like:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Some comments about what I've done"
```

Both operations are necessary. `add` add's it your index/staging area. `commit` actually creates a new commit object.

One way to check this would be, again from the command line:

```
$ git status
```

If it shows a a bunch of files that haven't been tracked and/or haven't been added to the staging area. This is your problem.

If it shows you that everything is up to date and unedited, then I would check to make sure that HEAD is pointing at a commit that doesn't match your remote.

One of the following could do that for you:

```
$ git log
$ gitk --all
```

If everything is as it should be, meaning that your local is all committed, and it has commits that remote does not, then I'd say the culprit lies with EGit, which I'm not an expert in.

Not that I'm a git expert, either. :)

---

If your intention is to have a remote place where you `push` from your local and have it update a file system with your latest changes, then you're barking up the wrong tree. [Remotes should always be bare repos, unless you really know what you're doing](http://book.git-scm.com/3_distributed_workflows.html).

It may be possible to write a [hook](http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html) on the remote repo that automatically checks out the `push`ed date, but again, that's discouraged. A more tenable solution would be to simply use [`git checkout-index...`](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/01/29/exporting-your-repository.html) and then scp/rsync/ftp your files to a flat store elsewhere. You could even write a hook to do this when you do a push somewhere or simply make a commit.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Tim. I suppose I certainly am barking up the wrong tree. 

I'm just so used to working under a subversion model where me and 1-2 other developers just always work on the mainline and merge conflicts when a commit conflict arises.

Is git different in that every developer is forced to create a new branch when working on the same source files? It seems like if it isn't, then the old source file will just get overridden with the last one pushed onto the repository.

Comment: I didn't know git provided a means for writing hooks. I'm definitely going to look into running an rsync on commits to the main repository.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely follow your process. Do you mean that you and a few other developers are working in the same physical directory at the same time? If that's not the case, then no, git does not force you to create new branches every time you want to work on the same file someone else is. Everyone can work on whatever files you want but when you want someone else change set, you need to merge it in. Git is very smart about merging, but conflicts can arise. In that case, you merge them, just as you're already doing. Maybe I can be clearer with some clarification on your end. :)